# populating missing values in panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill nan values  by mean of column by groupby subdivision column in a panda dataframe ...........
I used this:

```
  import pandas as pd 
  dataFrame = pd.read_csv("rainfall in india 1901-2015.csv")
  df=dataFrame.groupby("SUBDIVISION").transform(lambda x:x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

but it was missing the column SUBDIVISION in df...... How can I  resolve this?
and also tried to use this:

```
df2=dataFrame.groupby('SUBDIVISION').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

but it replace index values by Subdivision column values.

I don't have much idea about lambda .....
 my dataFrame(this contain NAN ) looks like this

```
                      SUBDIVISION  YEAR    JAN   ...       Mar-May  Jun-Sep  Oct-Dec
  0     ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS  1901   49.2   ...       560.3   1696.3    980.3
  1     ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS  1902    0.0   ...       458.3   2185.9    716.7
  2     ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS  1903   12.7   ...       236.1   1874.0    690.6
  3     ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS  1904    9.4   ...       506.9   1977.6    571.0
```

my df(NAN value replaced by mean but no SUBDIVISION column) look like

```
            YEAR    JAN    FEB     ...          Mar-May  Jun-Sep      Oct-Dec
      0     1901   49.2   87.1     ...       560.300000   1696.3   980.300000
      1     1902    0.0  159.8     ...       458.300000   2185.9   716.700000
      2     1903   12.7  144.0     ...       236.100000   1874.0   690.600000
      3     1904    9.4   14.7     ...       506.900000
```

df2 looks like 
in frond of df(NAN replaced by mean but extra column subdivision) there is a groupby column...

```
   SUBDIVISION                    ...
   ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS 0    ...
                             1    ...
                             2    ...
                             3    ...
                             4    ...
                             5    ...
                             6    ...
 please help me thanks in advance
```

i need df2 as answer but need to delete that column in frond of index

Comment: try `dataFrame.groupby('SUBDIVISION', as_index=False)`

Comment: Which column contains the values you want to calculate mean of?

Comment: index is not a column in  my csv file.... it is in dataframe. i think that it was an iterator for dataframe.......
in dataFrame. idex is 0 to 4000
in df idex is 0 to 4000 .............but,
in df2 it was same as 'SUBDIVISION' column..... why this?

Comment: Please provide some data to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: there are many columns like JAN .... DEC contain values of rainfall during that month.... and also have a column with ANNUL. with sum of all ...yearly rain fall

Comment: i was improved my question see